# Is there a Linux client for Amiga Explorer?

Tags: amiga, linux

I have some Amigas that I would like to be able to transfer files to/from using my primary desktop machine, a PC running Linux.

My Amigas do have CrossDOS installed, but transferring things in 720K chunks is tedious, made more so by the fact that I don't have a floppy drive regularly connected to my Linux box.

I have a copy of Amiga Forever that I purchased a few years ago, so I was thinking I could use the included Amiga Explorer tool. I installed the Amiga-side of this on my Amiga 1200 (using CrossDOS), but the official client is Windows-only. I found an open-source program called lxamiga that supposedly worked with an older version of Amiga Explorer, but it does not seem to work with recent versions.

Is there any Linux compatible client software for Amiga Explorer? If not, is the protocol it uses documented anywhere?

Alternatively, are there any other Linux-compatible tools for transferring files to and from Amigas? Something that works over a serial null modem or even a [parallel null modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LapLink_cable) cable would be ideal. (I do not have ethernet on any of my Amigas, unfortunately.)

Comment: Does Linux still have AFFS module in the kernel? I remember installing my Amiga HDD under Linux just fine (and then running UAE off it).

Comment: @SF. Ubuntu's kernels still ship with the affs module and I bet other distros' kernels do so as well. `sudo mount -t affs -o loop /path/to/image /mnt` should work with AmigaDOS-formatted ADF and HDF images.

Comment: @SF I've actually done this with the drive from my Amiga 2000HD: I borrowed a SCSI card, and was able to copy the entire drive in a matter of minutes. It surprised me at first how fast it was, but then I realized the drive was only 50MB. That said, I still would like the ability to transfer files from my Amigas as they are running, as I have a gazillion Amiga floppies, and moving HDDs between machines is kind of high overhead (especially since I don't own a SCSI adapter).

Comment: It is possible to use ADF Sender Terminal on wine and there is also a program called lxamiga. You can find more information about it on http://eab.abime.net/

Comment: Did any of the suggested solutions help? If so, you should select one of them as the proper answer.

Comment: Which version of lxamiga did you try? I haven't tried it myself but the one at https://github.com/marksmanuk/lxamiga is dated Dec 2017

Answer (score 12):

I don't know of any Linux-hosted software which is compatible with Amiga Explorer.

There are a number of other ways of transferring files to and from Amigas from Linux though. Over a null-modem cable, you can bootstrap file transfers using `type` to copy [`transwarp`](http://adfsender.stoeggl.com/adfsenderterminal/methods.html) across, then use that to copy files. In detail:

- on the Amiga, use `Serial` to set the serial port up as follows:

  - baud rate: 9600
  - buffer size: 512
  - handshake/protocol: RTS/CTS
  - parity: none
  - bits: 8
  - stop bits: 1
- on the Linux system, use `stty` to set the serial port up as follows:

  ```
  stty 9600 -parenb cs8 crtscts -ixon -ixoff raw iutf8 -F /dev/ttyS0
  ```

Your Amiga 1200 should have ARexx, so download [`receive.zip`](http://adfsender.stoeggl.com/utility/receive.zip), extract `receive.rexx` and transfer it:

- on the Linux system:

  ```
  cat receive.rexxlong > /dev/ttyS0
  ```
- on the Amiga:

  ```
  type SER: > receive.rexx
  ```
- because of the buffering on the Amiga side, pad the file out on the Linux side:

  ```
  for i in {1..200}; do echo -n " "; done > /dev/ttyS0
  ```

You should now be able to transfer files from Linux to the Amiga by `cat`ing them to `/dev/ttyS0` (or whichever serial port you're using) and running `rx receive` on the Amiga side. That way you can transfer [`transwarp`](http://adfsender.stoeggl.com/); that will allow you to transfer files from the Amiga to your Linux system, and use higher speeds.

The [Hombre](http://wiki.abime.net/file_transfer/hombre) page has more details, and covers other transfer methods. You might find [Amiga file transfer](http://www.boomerangsworld.de/cms/vc/amiga_transfer.html) useful too.

Answer (score 10):

Technically, the answer to your question is:
"No, there is no Linux client for Amiga explorer".

However, there are a few options to transfer files between modern computers and Amigas.

1. Parallel port.

   This is the most primitive solution and it requires that you have a computer with a parallel port, these can be quite rare. ;)
   There is an eBay vendor which sells the required cable and provides the necessary bootable floppy for both PC and Amiga.

   You can find more information about this on this English Amiga Board thread: http://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=65213
2. Compact Flash

   Second, you could get a Compact Flash Adapter for your Amiga.
   Write files on the PC/Mac side, then plug the card on the Amiga side.
   Still requires "swapping" as with floppies but at least you can transfer several GB of data each time rather than a meager 880KB.

   They are available for purchase here: http://amigakit.leamancomputing.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=440
3. Real Ethernet connection

   The **most practical solution** is to connect your Amiga to your computer's network. There are PCMCIA Ethernet cards for sale.

   If you google for "amiga 1200 network card" your first result will be a link to a seller with a complete solution. Note: I have no affiliation whatsoever with Leaman Computing, they are just the first Google result. ;)

There are more options, but some of them are still at the prototype stage so I won't be mentioning them here.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and welcome to the site! I cleaned up a little bit of the formatting, but all the content is brilliant. (If you use links to Amazon, Stack Exchange will get a referral bonus if the product is bought.)

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your exact question, but you could try running the software you have under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). Sometimes you get lucky, and it just works. Most APIs are well supported, though once you start needing interesting driver support all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to simply wire an RS-232 null modem cable between my Amiga and my PC.  If I load JRComm on my Amiga and similar terminal software on the PC (I am using Hyperterminal in Windows 98) I can send files back and forth using the old ZModem protocol.

I realize there may be slicker, newer, more efficient methods.  But this method works reliably and has a nice retro feel to it...

I don't have any experience with 'terminal' software under Linux, although I understand the shell can be redirected to the com port; so it may be as simple as finding a command line version of Zmodem (or Xmodem, or Ymodem, or Kermit).  But I can tell you from Windows Hyperterminal to Amiga JRComm over a null modem works perfectly at 19200.  I transfer stuff all the time...  good luck!

Comment: Also, before I got Star Commander (for the C64) and the Apple Disk Transfer (for Apple //) tools working, I would do the same serial/terminal/null modem technique to move files to/from my Apple's and Commodores...  It's completely idiot proof. :-)